# Windows Phone Facebook post photo

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

I am having problem posting the photo to the facebook.Anybody know how to it. Please help. Thanks.

```
  FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);

                fb.PostCompleted += (o, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Error != null)
                    {
                        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message));
                        return;
                    }

                    var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();

                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Success post message to the wall.");
                        // reset the selections after the post action has successfully concluded
                        tbmessage.Text = "";
                    });
                };

                var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                parameters["name"] = tbmessage.Text;

                dynamic res = fb.PostTaskAsync("me/photos", parameters);
```

Comment: In ques you said, `problem posting the photo`; but in code you are `posting feed`- what exactly are you looking for? And what errors are you getting?

Comment: I know how to post to feed, now I dont know how to attach with photo

Comment: Pls edit you ques, its very misleading. Also, you want a picture to be posted on the wall or the feed? Both are different concepts.

Comment: Why are you not posting the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

In the parameters list, you have to provide the image source by either of the following:

- `url` : a valid url to the image
- `source`: iamge data

**[Code]**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostPhotoOnWall(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        var filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
        Uri jpegUri = new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative);
        sri = Application.GetResourceStream(jpegUri);
        byte[] imageData = new byte[sri.Stream.Length];
        sri.Stream.Read(imageData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(sri.Stream.Length));

        var client = new FacebookClient();

        // Post to user's wall
        var postparameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var media = new FacebookMediaObject
        {
            FileName = filename,
            ContentType = "image/jpeg"
        };
        media.SetValue(imageData);

        postparameters["source"] = media;
        postparameters["access_token"] = Session["access_token"].ToString();

        var result = client.Post("/me/photos", postparameters);

        return View("PostPhoto");
    }
```

Comment: Shadowfax do you know how to upload photo to facebook from the local storage

Comment: Yes, just provide the `image raw data` to the field: `source`

Comment: Is it use     parameters["source"] = new FacebookMediaObject ? sorry new to WP development .

Comment: Yes, I've added some code that might help you. PS: accept the answer if helped!

Comment: shadowfax,thx for your answer but I get system.io.file' does not contain a definition for readallbytes'

Comment: the ImageData is missing ?

Comment: Shadowfax still cannot,http://pastebin.com/BD58GXmq It is glad if you can help me. I totally no idea. Please help.thanks

Comment: Are you getting the imageData correctly? What error message you are getting from facebook

Comment: NullException at   sri = Application.GetResourceStream(jpegUri);

Comment: You are passing the `url`, you cannot just work on the url, you need the file. My function requires the `file`. If you search, you'll get the clue